# Defining an operation on a quotient set

Tags: abstract-algebra

I found the following exercise in the beginning of Ames *An Introduction to Abstract Algebra*. (I left out a few parts.)

---

$f$ is a map $G\mapsto G'$ of two groups.  For any $x'\in Gf,$ take $f^{-1}(x')=\{x\in G|xf=x'\}$

Show that the subsets $f^{-1}(x')$ for $x'\in Gf$ form a quotient set $Q$ of $G$

Prove that the mapping $g$ of $Q\mapsto Gf$ defined by $qg=x',$ where $q=f^{-1}(x')$ is a bijection.

Hence show that $g$ defines a binary operation in $Q$ which makes $Q$ a group.  (See Exercise 1, Sec. 1-3.)

---

The referenced exercise talks about defining a binary operation on a group $A$ by the binary operation on a group $B$ if we have a bijection $h\colon A\mapsto B.$  I'm confused because I'm pretty sure of each of the following:

1. The only candidate for a binary operation is the one defined on G.
2. $Gf,$ the image of $Q$ under the bijection, is not (in general) a group.
3. (1) and (2) mean there's no way to use $g$ to make $Q$ into a group.

What am I missing?

Comment: 1. G' also has a binary operation. 2. Isn't Gf the image of G under the group map f? In which case, it's a subgroup of G'.

Comment: @Billy 1. Yeah, I just forgot to write that.  2. Yes, but why does that make it a subgroup if $f$ is an arbitrary map?  Does the phrase "a mapping $G\mapsto G'$ of groups" just mean that its image is a group?

Comment: No, it means that f is a group homomorphism. (That is, if * is the operation on G and # is the operation on G', we have f(g * h) = f(g)#f(h) for all g and h in G.) But group homomorphisms *do* have the property that images are still groups.

Comment: Ahh, ok thanks. That thought crossed my mind at one point, but he hadn't defined homomorphism yet, so I thought not.

Comment: Oh, strange. I don't know the book. In any case, if f isn't a homomorphism, there's no guarantee that Q (or Gf) is a group, so that must be what he means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered by Billy in the comments, but I'll post it as an answer so it has an answer.

Point 2. is incorrect because $f$ is a homomorphism.